# How to set an expired authentication in Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication, session

Using a simple virtual host, I want to set a timeout of X minutes (same of set an expired authentication) to force the user to re-insert its credentials.

```
[...]
<Directory /home/user1/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
        Options -FollowSymLinks +Indexes +Includes -MultiViews
        IndexOptions +IgnoreCase +SuppressDescription +FoldersFirst +NameWidth=40 +SuppressHTMLPreamble +FancyIndexing +IconHeight=16 +IconWidth=16
        AllowOverride none
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/user1.pass
        AuthName "server.example.com"
        AuthType Digest
        require valid-user
</Directory>
[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First

As I know apache/HTTP authentication don't gives you control.
After first authentication, your server cannot instruct the browser to logout or timeout, because HTTP authentication doesn't work with session/cookies and the browser will continuously send authentication credentials. To logout you should close the browser.

but looking in Apache webpage:
`AuthDigestNonceLifetime` Directive might be useful

from apache web page:

> The AuthDigestNonceLifetime directive controls how long the server nonce is valid. When the client contacts the server using an expired nonce the server will send back a 401 with stale=true. If seconds is greater than 0 then it specifies the amount of time for which the nonce is valid; this should probably never be set to less than 10 seconds. If seconds is less than 0 then the nonce never expire